# Convert MS Word specific tags and style to HTML using javascript(Paste From Word feature)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ms-word

I am developing a Text Editor and I want to provide an option called "**Paste From Word**".

**About Text Editor I am using:**

The text editor is purely based on HTML 5, CSS and Javascript. Now I want to provide an option called "**Paste From Word**".

**What I have used:**

I found some solution on GitHub and below is the code I tried to remove all MS-Word related classes(like **MSoNormal**) and MS-Word related tags(like **w:sdt**):

**Code I tried:**

```
function CleanWordHTML(str) {
str = str.replace(/<o:p>\s*<\/o:p>/g, "");
str = str.replace(/<o:p>.*?<\/o:p>/g, "&nbsp;");
str = str.replace(/\s*mso-[^:]+:[^;"]+;?/gi, "");
str = str.replace(/\s*MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt\s*;/gi, "");
str = str.replace(/\s*MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt\s*"/gi, "\"");
str = str.replace(/\s*TEXT-INDENT: 0cm\s*;/gi, "");
str = str.replace(/\s*TEXT-INDENT: 0cm\s*"/gi, "\"");
str = str.replace(/\s*TEXT-ALIGN: [^\s;]+;?"/gi, "\"");
str = str.replace(/\s*PAGE-BREAK-BEFORE: [^\s;]+;?"/gi, "\"");
str = str.replace(/\s*FONT-VARIANT: [^\s;]+;?"/gi, "\"");
str = str.replace(/\s*tab-stops:[^;"]*;?/gi, "");
str = str.replace(/\s*tab-stops:[^"]*/gi, "");
str = str.replace(/\s*face="[^"]*"/gi, "");
str = str.replace(/\s*face=[^ >]*/gi, "");
str = str.replace(/\s*FONT-FAMILY:[^;"]*;?/gi, "");
str = str.replace(/<(\w[^>]*) class=([^ |>]*)([^>]*)/gi, "<$1$3");
str = str.replace(/<(\w[^>]*) style="([^\"]*)"([^>]*)/gi, "<$1$3");
str = str.replace(/\s*style="\s*"/gi, '');
str = str.replace(/<SPAN\s*[^>]*>\s*&nbsp;\s*<\/SPAN>/gi, '&nbsp;');
str = str.replace(/<SPAN\s*[^>]*><\/SPAN>/gi, '');
str = str.replace(/<(\w[^>]*) lang=([^ |>]*)([^>]*)/gi, "<$1$3");
str = str.replace(/<SPAN\s*>(.*?)<\/SPAN>/gi, '$1');
str = str.replace(/<FONT\s*>(.*?)<\/FONT>/gi, '$1');
str = str.replace(/<\\?\?xml[^>]*>/gi, "");
str = str.replace(/<\/?\w+:[^>]*>/gi, "");
str = str.replace(/<H\d>\s*<\/H\d>/gi, '');
str = str.replace(/<H1([^>]*)>/gi, '');
str = str.replace(/<H2([^>]*)>/gi, '');
str = str.replace(/<H3([^>]*)>/gi, '');
str = str.replace(/<H4([^>]*)>/gi, '');
str = str.replace(/<H5([^>]*)>/gi, '');
str = str.replace(/<H6([^>]*)>/gi, '');
str = str.replace(/<\/H\d>/gi, '<br>'); //remove this to take out breaks where Heading tags were 
str = str.replace(/<(U|I|STRIKE)>&nbsp;<\/\1>/g, '&nbsp;');
str = str.replace(/<(B|b)>&nbsp;<\/\b|B>/g, '');
str = str.replace(/<([^\s>]+)[^>]*>\s*<\/\1>/g, '');
str = str.replace(/<([^\s>]+)[^>]*>\s*<\/\1>/g, '');
str = str.replace(/<([^\s>]+)[^>]*>\s*<\/\1>/g, '');
//some RegEx code for the picky browsers
var re = new RegExp("(<P)([^>]*>.*?)(<\/P>)", "gi");
str = str.replace(re, "<div$2</div>");
var re2 = new RegExp("(<font|<FONT)([^*>]*>.*?)(<\/FONT>|<\/font>)", "gi");
str = str.replace(re2, "<div$2</div>");
str = str.replace(/size|SIZE = ([\d]{1})/g, '');
return str;
}
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

On pasting into my text editor from MS-Word, I need to replace the following with the respective HTML styles and tags:

1. Remove HTML tags which is related to MS-Word like **w:sdt**
2. Remove classes from the elements(as shown below):

   style="mso-element:para-border-div;border:none;border-bottom:solid 
     #EA4E4E 6.0pt; mso-border-bottom-themecolor:accent1;padding:0cm 0cm 1.0pt 0cm"
3. Make Pasted Content free from MS-Word related styles, but, the **Formatting should be retained by HTML with the respective replacement.**

**NOTE:**

I tried looking into many sites but could not find any plugin or any solution. ***Even if start writing on my own javascript to achieve this functionality, I do not know what are all the classes and tags that MS-Word Uses.***

*Overall, I need the functionality to replace MS-Word related tags and styles into the HTML content with MS-Word related tags and styles removed.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should clone the elements structure by traversing it. You should use the same type of elements, the same inline style and the same text contents, but the rest should not be needed. So, it is more about removing everything and just taking what you need, instead of removing what you don't need.

Comment: For taking what I need, I need to know what I don't need which is where the tags and styles comes here. Is there any plugin out there to achieve this functionality ? Or could you explain me further  on this, so that, I can understand your suggestion in a well versed manner ?